# Why is left NumberPadding always applied in NumberForm?

Tags: functions, numerics, formatting, language-design

I would like to display numbers like `9.0001` and `10.0001` in the fixed-width form of `xx.xxxx`. This seems like a perfect job for:

```
NumberForm[#, {6, 4}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}] & /@ {9.0001, 10.0001}
```

But this returns `{009.0001, 010.0001}`, which has one extra leading zero.

Reducing the number of digits doesn't fix this.

```
NumberForm[#, {5, 4}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}] & /@ {9.0001, 10.0001}

{09.0001,010.0000}
```

Why is at least one copy of the left NumberPadding always being added, even when this makes the total number of digits exceed `n`, the desired total number of digits?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thanks for the reminder. While your answer contains a good solution to the problem, m_goldberg's answers the exact question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *Mathematica* is padding one extra position on the left to preserve space for a possible minus sign.

```
NumberForm[#, {6, 4}, NumberPadding -> {"*", "0"}] & /@ 
  {1234.567, -1234.567, 12.34567, -12.34567, 1.234567, -1.234567}
```

> ```
>  {*1234.5700, -1234.5700, *12.3457, -12.3457, **1.2346, *-1.2346}
> ```